# Websphere Portal 8 login service check existing password correct

Tags: ldap, portlet, websphere-portal, puma

I have a portlet that is used to change the password of the logged in user. The user has to enter their current password and a new password twice. It calls the LoginService.checkPassword(String userId, char[] password) to determine if the existing password is correct. If this method returns true, then the password is updated by getting the current user via the Puma Profile and setting the updated attribute using the PumaController.setAttributes(User user, Map attributes) call. Then the puma profile is reloaded via the PumaProfile.reload method (I've also tried using the PumaController.reload() method.

The problem I'm facing is that the LoginService.checkPassword(String userId, char[] password) is returning true for the current password and also older passwords rather than just for the current password. Does anyone know why this would be?

In ldap the password field is a single attribute field, as it is also in wimdomain.xml, and if I log out and try to log in, I can only log in with the current password (as you would expect).

Comment: Guess that depends on what the "LoginService.checkPassword(String userId, char[] password)" method does with LDAP. 
Is it a compare?

Many LDAP implementations will never return the actual password.

Perhaps a LDAP trace would reveal the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found it's a bug in Portal. Even if you use the out of the box profile edit portlet, you get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Verify Websphere Portal User's Password
There are two ways to verify user's password -

1) Use "UserRegistry"

```
public static boolean checkUserAuthenticatedLDAP(String userId, String password) {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry reg =
            (com.ibm.websphere.security.UserRegistry) ctx.lookup("UserRegistry");

        String res = reg.checkPassword(userId, password);

        return res != null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

2) Use "LoginContext"

```
/**
 * This method validates the user based on the user id and password
 * attributes, If the user id or password is not valid then throws Exception.
 *
 * @param userId
 * @param password
 * @return boolean
 * @throws Exception
 */
public boolean checkUserAuthenticated(String userId, String password) throws Exception {
    javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext loginContext = null;

    Subject subject = null;

    try {
        loginContext = new javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext("WSLogin",
            new com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.callback.WSCallbackHandlerImpl(userId, password));
    } catch (javax.security.auth.login.LoginException e) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot create LoginContext", e);
    }

    try {
        loginContext.login();

        subject = loginContext.getSubject();
    } catch (com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSLoginFailedException e) {
        throw new Exception("Password is incorrect", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Unknown username", e);
    }

    if (subject == null)
        throw new Exception("Password is incorrect");

    return true;
}
```